# In NgRx, where to transform the response data from a server (got through side effects) to a state which the component understands?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am new to NgRx hence the confusion.
I have a simple component which shows a list of objects e.g. Orders.
It gets the list of Orders to be shown from backend using an Effect.
Only problem is I want to transform this response from the BE into a simple list of objects to show in the component.
I am confused as to where to transform it. I see 4 options:

1. Transform it in the service that gets the list from the backend - Quite simple to implement not sure if its the best way.
2. Transform it in the effect - If here then why not in the service?
3. Transform it using the reducer - Seems like a valid place.
4. Transform it using a selector - We won't need a view state as the view state will be derived from the selector every time a component is opened. May be even make it slow because it has to transform the state every time.

This is my understanding so far. I would like to know if its correct and I would also like to know the best practice to handle this case which seems should be fairly common in applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have:

- a component where you need your list
- a service where you do http requests
- a state, ngrx

steps:

1. a) from the component, dispatch an action - to get the list
   b) in component, listen to the listAction (to receive new data)

   ```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.dispatch(getListAction); // this will fire the action

    this.store.pipe(
       select(fromStore.selectList)
    ).subscribe(yourList => {
       // here you have the list
    });
   ```

   }

2. actions.ts

   ```
    export enum Types {
          GET_LIST = '[Store Type] Get List',
          GET_LIST_SUCCESS = '[Store Type] Get List Success',
          GET_LIST_FAILED = '[Store Type] Get List Failed',
        } 

    export const getListAction = createAction(
      Types.GET_LIST // this will be fired from component, and will fire the store effect
    );
    export const getListSuccessAction = createAction(
      Types.GET_LIST_SUCCESS, // this will be fired when service return the list
      props<{list: obj_type[]}>
    );
   export const getListFailedAction = createAction(
      Types.GET_LIST_FAILED, // this will be fired when service throws error
      props<{msg: string}>
    );
   ```
3. effects.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyEffects {
    
     constructor(service: YourService) {
    }
        
         getList$ = createEffect(() =>
            this.actions$.pipe(
              ofType(getListAction),
              switchMap(() =>
                this.your_service.getList().pipe(
                  tap((list) => getListSuccessAction({list})),
                  catchError((error) =>
                    of(getListFailedAction({ msg: error.message }))
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          );
        }
```

4. reducer.ts

   `````
   export const reducer = createReducer(
     initialState,
     on(getListAction, (state) => ({
       ...state,
       request: PENDING
     })),
     on(getListSuccessAction, (state, { list}) => ({
       // your component store.pipe(select) will be fired with data from here
       ...state,
       list: 
       request: COMPLETED
     })),
     on(getListFailedAction, (state, { msg }) => ({
       ...state,
       error: {msg},
       request: FAILED
     }))
   );````
   `````
5. selectors.ts

```
    export const selectState = (state: AppState) => state;
    
    export const selectList =
      createSelector(selectState , (state) =>
        state.list);
```

Comment: So "on(getListSuccessAction, (state, { list}) => ({ " this is transforming the response from the server to the state right?

Answer (score 1):

This is less of an ngrx question, and more of a client-server mapping question.

In my experience, the best practice is to map as close to the api as possible - so in this case, in the service that gets it from the BE.

Note that you could also make a specific service for mapping, and have it called from the API service - this would be dependent on just exactly how verbose your API service is